# Check if a site is being blocked by internal proxy / network

Tags: windows, ping

I'm just wondering how to check whether a site is being blocked on my work network, can I simply Ping it?

I just want to know so that I can not visit it, the site is imgur.com

Comment: Sure, just ping it.

Comment: quite broad; some allow pings - some block pings - some allow pings & http requests and return a plain "BLOCKED" page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a tracert to it. If it stops before it leaves your network, then it's being blocked. However, a possible workaround a block is using `https`, instead of the standard `http`. This only has a *chance* of working if the site supports it. In you're case, imgur.com does support it.

Try this link: https://imgur.com

Comment: not necessarily, several routers block ICMP packets causing traceroute to fail. Example: [Why can I ping an IP address but not 'traceroute' it?](http://superuser.com/q/278952)